# Advanced URL Queries

Tags: javascript, string, url

so I have a bit of a problem I'm trying to sort out and I've only been doing development for under a year so things are still pretty new to me. My goal is to create a script which is capable of finding the utm values in the url if they exist and to then store them into variables, if they exist. I've gotten a script working, but it only works if the url is structured in a very specific way,

localhost/?utm_source=google&utm_medium=cpc&utm_campaign=(roi)+cdn+general&utm_content=cdn+(phrase+%26+broad)&utm_term=cdn&gclid=CNaV2vnZl7wCFY57QgodbgwA7A

It could be a variety of urls in actual production, e.g. -

localhost/?utm_source=google&utm_medium=cpc&utm_campaign=(roi)+cdn+general
localhost/?utm_source=google&utm_medium=cpc&utm_campaign=(roi)+cdn+general&utm_content=cdn+(phrase+%26+broad)&utm_term=cdn

Here is the code I've put together so far. If you have any advice on how to get it to work better in all circumstances, or any resources you would recommend to an "advanced beginner," I'd be most appreciative!

```
var urlSearch = window.location.search;

        if (urlSearch.length > 1) {

        if (urlSearch.match('utm_source=(.*)&utm_medium')) {
            var utmSource = urlSearch.match('utm_source=(.*)&utm_medium')[1];
        }

        if (urlSearch.match('utm_medium=(.*)&utm_campaign')) {
            var utmMedium = urlSearch.match('utm_medium=(.*)&utm_campaign')[1];
        }

        if (urlSearch.match('utm_campaign=(.*)&utm_content')) {
            var utmCampaign = urlSearch.match('utm_campaign=(.*)&utm_content')[1];
        }

        if (urlSearch.match('utm_content=(.*)&utm_term')) {
            var utmContent = urlSearch.match('utm_content=(.*)&utm_term')[1];
        }

        if (urlSearch.match('utm_term=(.*)&')) {
            var utmTerm = urlSearch.match('utm_term=(.*)&')[1];
        }

    }
```

Comment: Take a look at this article I wrote. It will completely parse all variables from the query string into a JavaScript object. There are also other examples of code on Stack Overflow. http://www.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/javascript/article.php/11877_3755006_2/How-to-Use-a-JavaScript-Query-String-Parser.htm

Answer (score 0):

The specific problem with your approach is that the query string is not guaranteed to be in a specific order. So your code will stop working if any changes in a browser or a previous page cause the query string variables to be submitted in a different order. There are some other problems, too, just one of which is decoding any spaces or complicated values.

Use a query string parser, like this example:

```
<title>JavaScript Form Processor</title>


<script>
function ptq(q)
{
    /* parse the query */
    /* semicolons are nonstandard but we accept them */
    var x = q.replace(/;/g, '&').split('&'), i, name, t;
    /* q changes from string version of query to object */
    for (q={}, i=0; i<x.length; i++)
    {
        t = x[i].split('=', 2);
        name = unescape(t[0]); /* unescape can and should be replaced with decodeURIComponent() for almost all browsers */
        if (!q[name])
            q[name] = [];
        if (t.length > 1)
        {
            q[name][q[name].length] = unescape(t[1]);
        }
        /* next two lines are nonstandard */
        else
            q[name][q[name].length] = true;
    }
    return q;
}

function param() {
    return ptq(location.search.substring(1).replace(/\+/g, ' '));
}
q = param();

firstname = q.name1;
/* use q['name1'] syntax to access more complicated variables from the query string */
document.write('<h1>Hello ', firstname || 'Anonymous', '!</h1>');
</script>
<form>
Type your first name: <input type="text" name="name1" />
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

In order to parse the variables that you mention in your question, you would simply use the `q` variable that is created in the above script, and access its properties:

```
        var utmSource = q.utm_source, utmMedium = q.utm_medium, etc.;
```